# basis representation of a special sinc kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, sp.spectral-theory, integral-kernel, kernels

I have a functional map from $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ to another function $f_{x,y}(z,w) \in \mathbb{C}$. (Variables $z,w $ range from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.) That is, for any pair $x,y$, I get a complex-valued function that has domain $\mathbb{R}^2$. 
For my set of functions $f_{x,y}(z,w)$, I managed to prove 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{x,y}(z,w)f_{x+\delta_x,y+\delta_y}^\ast(z,w)\mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}w = \mathrm{sinc}\left(\sqrt{\delta_x^2+\delta_y^2}\right),$$
(where $\mathrm{sinc}(1)=0$).

I now wonder about a basis for such signals, in particular its size.
Let $(x,y) \in \mathcal{A}\subset \mathcal{R}^2$.
Then I would like to express 
$$f_{x,y}(z,w)=\sum_{\ell}^L a_{\ell}(x,y) \phi_{\ell}(z,w)$$
for some basis functions $\phi_{\ell}(z,w)$ and expansion coefficients.
What would be the "density" of basis functions,
$$\lim_{|\mathcal{A}|\to \infty} \frac{1}{|\mathcal{A}|}L$$
required to capture (close to) all of the energy in $f_{x,y}(z,w)$ ? That is, how many basis functions are needed per $m^2$ (assuming that $(x,y)$ are coordinates in physical space) ?

I have a feeling that this is related to prolate spheroidal wave functions, but never worked with 2D-pswfs

Comment: For the record, at time of writing this question has attracted a vote to close as "unclear what you're asking". I strongly disagree with this reason given, although I am unsure if the question should stay open